# How to create a refraction plane in the BGE?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I need a *refraction* plane.
What refraction script should I use to create many planes?

Imagine what every plate is window made with similar to RenderToTexture script. For ex.: I want to create house and add 3 windows made of similar to Render To Texture script. And the main question is: How many planes can I use with this script? Do I need other script for it, bit more advanced? Please, suggest me any possibility solution. :)

Comment: Please don't erase the question or mark it as solved!. The idea behind this site is not a personalized help support where once you are satisfied with an answer no one has access to the information anymore.  The point is quite the opposite: we are looking for questions and answers that can be referenced by other users down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only limit of this script is your Hardware configuration (RAM, GPU, CPU).

You can use the fake reflections too, with a texture and in the **Texture pannel**, replace the Mapping Coordinates to "**Reflection**" (Use **GLSL** for see in real time).

Many games use the fake reflection, but the camera may move for see the correct fake reflections.

Here a blend with reflection texture that i made (Gold texture):

https://mega.nz/#!qlNARDoY!W9FotR5a0zFJ-XXgUHFXLqDSaN6eVw56bzw9vBOxf_I

Comment: Thanks, but I'm searching for solution to create **clean refraction plane** with ability to apply 2D filters or other python scripts :) And to apply this for separate planes to create 3 and more windows for the house, with each rendered refraction plane which each have different views under plane. At first I need refraction plane clean like a glass but with ability to apply **refraction thing** to other 2 windows same thing. I don't want to use z-transparency, becouse it's not a script and it have no possibilities to add any filters on plane refraction.

Comment: Its a really cool idea, maybe you need a sort of blur 2d filter for your plane.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvfvCURIcT4